# Update and insert multiple documents in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkinsert, insert-update, bulkupdate

I was trying to update and insert many input documents into mongodb.
I found many resources, but didn't get the optimal solution except `bulkWrite`.
My documents looks like below.

```
[
    {
        pId: "p1",
        apikey: "a2",
        primaryKey: "key1",
        type: "augmented"
        flag: "train",
        count: 0,
        createdAt: 1622128794647
    },
    {
        pId: "p2",
        apikey: "a2",
        primaryKey: "key2",
        type: "augmented"
        flag: "train",
        count: 0,
        createdAt: 1600258007285
    }
]
```

If `pId`, `apikey` and `primaryKey` matches then count should be increased, otherwise it will create a new documents
I have an huge array of objects.
Using loop I was trying to do `bulkWrite` like below.
is there any possible solution for this, will it be costlier if my input documents is huge like more (5k or 10k).

```
inputDocs.map(input=>{
    const { pId, apikey, primaryKey }=input;
    let ops =[];
    ops.push(
        {
            updateOne:{
                filter:{
                    pId,
                    apikey,
                    primaryKey
                },
                update:{
                    "$inc":{
                        count: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            updateOne:{
                filter:{
                    pId,
                    apikey,
                    primaryKey
                },
                update:{
                    "$set":{
                        ...input,
                        count: 0,
                        createdAt: Date.now(),
                        updatedAt: Date.now()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
    db.collection("process").bulkWrite(ops);
});
```

Comment: What is the question here? Efficiency, the only positive of bulkwrite is you are saved from the network round trip, are you doing ordered or unordered  writes? There are no problem as such.

Comment: Hi, i was doing unordered writes and wanted to see without looping each and every input dcoument how can insert or update, thanks:)

Comment: So are you trying to update the same document that you are inserting with the bulkwrite? :D I hope not, rest seems okay to me.

Comment: ok, and can we do increment if exists else insert in bulk write, here is a glitch, when `filter` matches in first `updateOne` it increased by 1, and in second query, it resets to 0, when I am using `upsert`

Comment: Use ordered then :D That is why I asked that clearly.

Comment: can you please answer the query, I wanted to see how it looks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233227/discussion-between-abinas-patra-and-gandalf-the-white).